# Why does my Django CreateView not recognise form_valid

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am using the django allauth module to create a user. In **views,py** I am subclassing CreateView, but I cannot get *form_valid* to work. It seems not to be being called (I have not imported HttpResponseRedirect but it doesn't complain

```
class SignupPageView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'registration/signup.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print('form_valid')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())


    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print('form_invalid') 
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I have also added *form_invalid* and it still doesn't fail. This leads me to think that something fundamental is awry.

The user registration process seems to function correctly and no errors are reported

The html associated with the form is

```
{% extends '_base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}Sign Up{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form | crispy }}
        <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', SignupPageView.as_view(), name='signup'),
]
```

Comment: Is form valid ?

Comment: Put a print statement inside the `form_invalid()` and try again. Probably your form isn't valid and hence the execution is not reaching the `form_valid()` method.

Comment: The problem could be in your URL patterns or the template.

Answer (score 0):

[CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView) inherits methods of [FormMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#formmixin) which has both `form_valid` and `form_invalid`. So there's nothing wrong with your CBV declaration.

So I think that your form just isn't valid. Could you try to add `form_invalid` method and see if it would be called?

Comment: form_invalid is not called either

Comment: Could you update your question to show the url pattern used to call this view?

Comment: I've added the html and urls.py

Comment: What do you see when you enter `/signup` page?

Comment: the form with 4 fields: email, username, password1, password2. The form works as expected: correct validations, a user is created and an email sent

Comment: I suggest to add "raise" in both methods and reload your app. How do you reload your app? Do you use regualr "runserver? uwsgi?

Comment: just 'raise'? doesn't make any difference - runserver

Comment: Did you stop and start your server before checks? Because it's really strange :)

Comment: yes I did - I do not get error messages on the login form either

Comment: Just curious what if you change template name to something bad - eg “signup111.html”?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225459/discussion-between-psionman-and-dmitry-belaventsev).